# Proving by induction: If $x + \frac{1}{x} = 2 \cos(\cos\theta)$, then $x^n + \frac{1}{x^n} = 2\cos(\cos(n\theta))$

Tags: trigonometry, induction

A math competition for 11 and 12th graders asked us to solve this.

> Given: $$x + \frac{1}{x} = 2 \cos(\cos\theta)$$
>
> Prove:
> $$x^n + \frac{1}{x^n} = 2\cos(\cos(n\theta))$$

We just managed to prove it works for n =1 by using the equation given, but thats about it

Nobody managed to solve it, not even our teacher after the fact.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Did you search already? [This post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3112674/if-x-frac1x-2-cos-theta-then-find-the-value-of-xn-frac1xn?noredirect=1&lq=1) is popular, but it has $\cos(\theta)$ and not $\cos(\cos(\theta))$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Difference between the problem you linked and mine is that there is a cos function inside another one, cos(cos(θ)), instead of just cos(θ)

Comment: Still, it is an idea how to solve it - since you said nobody managed anything. So it is at least a start. You should explain what you have tried (to avoid a "no clue" question).

Comment: @AlbanianUltra: The nested cosines make the result false. For instance, $\theta=\pi/2$ and $x=1$ satisfy the "given", but not the "prove" for every $n>1$. (They work for *some* values of $n$, however.)

Comment: Take a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_polynomials

Answer (score 2):

When $x\in \mathbb{R}\setminus 0$ we have that $x+\frac 1x \in ]-\infty,-2]\cup[2,+\infty[$. On the other hand, $2\cos(\cos \theta) \in [2 \cos 1, 2]$. So, the only way that you can have $x+\frac 1x = 2 \cos(\cos \theta)$ is with $x = 1$ and $\cos \theta = 0$.

However, even for $x=1$ and $\cos \theta = 0$, the statement does not hold for every $n$.